# Apache, PHP and Percona Database

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xtradb, percona

I have just upgraded MySQL 5.0 to Percona XtraDB 5.1. I had to yum remove all the mysql stuff first. Everything was working fine, until I restarted Apache and now I get:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Any ideas? I have a feeling I removed some sort of mysql plugin for apache at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the php-mysql library.  Depending on your distribution, this may have a slightly different name.  Also,  I was just experimenting with this on Ubuntu 11.04.  Ended up going back to MySQL because PHP-MySQL wouldn't install without libmysqlcient16 which wouldn't install because it conflicted with percona.  Hopefully, you don't run into the same problems that I did.

Comment: right answer. I didn't have any problesm with just running yum install php-mysql on centos 5

Answer (score 0):

I use the following functional configuration with PHP and Percona on at least 150 servers:

```
Percona-Server-shared-55-5.5.30-rel30.2.509.rhel6.x86_64
Percona-Server-client-55-5.5.30-rel30.2.509.rhel6.x86_64
Percona-Server-server-55-5.5.30-rel30.2.509.rhel6.x86_64
Percona-Server-devel-55-5.5.30-rel30.2.509.rhel6.x86_64
Percona-Server-shared-compat-5.5.30-rel30.2.509.rhel6.x86_64

php-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-xml-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-pdo-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.3.3-1.el6.x86_64
php-xmlrpc-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
```

As for the error libmysqlcient16.so is, resolvable by installing Percona-Server-shared-compat-[version].rpm.